# Where are the username and password stored in a PHP program when you are using HTTP authentication?

Tags: http-authentication

Where are the username and password stored in a PHP program when you are
using HTTP authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']

Source: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php